# Spring Kafka dead message Queue and retries

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, dead-letter

I have a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfig {

    final DlqErrorHandler dlqErrorHandler;

    public ConsumerConfig(DlqErrorHandler dlqErrorHandler) {
        this.dlqErrorHandler = dlqErrorHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id_two");
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        factory.setErrorHandler(dlqErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

There is an implementation of the error handler:

```
@Component
public class DlqErrorHandler implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler {
    private final KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

    public DlqErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception e, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> list, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = list.get(0);

        try {
            kafkaTemplate.send("dlqTopic", record.key(), record.value());
            consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), record.offset() + 1);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), record.offset());
            throw new KafkaException("Seek to current after exception", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two listeners:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "batchProcessingWithRetryPolicy", containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println(message + " NORMAL");
        if (message.equals("TEST ERROR")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("EEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORRRRRR");
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "dlqTopic", containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeTwo(String message) {
        System.out.println(message + " DQL");
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("EEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORRRRRR ");
        }
    }
}
```

My question:

1)

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
```

Method setAckOnError - deprecated. How can I replace this line of code so that the first listener after an error when processing a message does not make repeated attempts, but sends this message to DQL.

2. How do I set a limit for DQL (DlqErrorHandler) on repetitions and time intervals between sending messages? That is, after the first error, the message appears in DQL, then I want to make 3 more attempts with an interval of 30 seconds and if it does not work, then go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ackOnError` is replaced by `ErrorHandler.isAckAfterHandle()`.

Your error handler implementation is incomplete - you need to seek the other partitions in the remaining records list as well.

Why don't you just use the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` provided by the framework. They support your use case.